# x-forwarded-for header not passed by AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

My tomcat application is not receiving X-Forwarded-For header from AWS Application load balancer. The load balancer is configured to offload SSL and connects with the tomcat application over HTTP. I am receiving other headers such as x-forwarded-proto, x-forwarded-port, x-amzn-trace-id. I am trying to find the client ip address but now stuck with it. I have also checked all the headers that I am receiving to find out the client ip address but it's just not there. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to the tomcat configurations. Check whether you got following configs in tomcat to handle both `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-proto` headers

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>protocolHeader</param-name>
      <param-value>x-forwarded-proto</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Here's the configuration reference :https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Basic_configuration_to_handle_'x-forwarded-for'*and*'x-forwarded-proto'

You can find the configuration file in either `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` or application's WEB-INF/web.xml

> Tomcat provides a number of Filters which may be configured for use
>   with all web applications using $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml or may be
>   configured for individual web applications by configuring them in the
>   application's WEB-INF/web.xml.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  `X-Forwarded-For` is passed by AWS Load Balancers, and needs to be configured in Tomcat to be used subsequently.

Comment: Thanks Anuruddha & Tom for the quick response. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Anuruddha, a naive question. Why is this configuration required. Does tomcat doesn't send the `x-forwarded-for` header to application code without this filter?

Comment: What does the Tomcat filter have to do with anything? Does it 'eat' the header or something?